# why can I not insert data in phpMyAdmin mysql

Tags: php

i have problems inserting data, it does not enter any data to my phpmyadmin im having problems

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$LastName=$_POST['LastName'];
$FirstName=$_POST['FirstName'];
$MiddleInitial=$_POST['MiddleInitial'];
$Age=$_POST['Age'];
$Gender=$_POST['Gender'];
$Birthday=$_POST['Birthday'];
$Address=$_POST['Address'];
$EmailAddress=$_POST['EmailAddress'];

mysql_query("insert into studentsrecords(LastName,FirstName,MiddleInitial,Age,Gender,Birthday,Address,EmailAddress)
values('$LastName','$$FirstName','$MiddleInitial','$Age','$Gender','$Birthday','$Address','$EmailAddress',NOW())
")or die(mysql_error());
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
alert('You are Successfully Register Thank You');
window.location="index.php";
</script>

<?php
}
?>
```

this is my config.php

Comment: and where is your `mysql_connect` function?

Comment: [mysql_query](http://www.php.net/manual/tr/function.mysql-query.php) _Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used._

Comment: What does this have to do with phpMyAdmin?

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: <?php
mysql_select_db('rotc',mysql_connect('localhost','root',''))or die(mysql_error());
?>

Comment: For one thing, you have more values than your INSERT. I.e.: `NOW()`

Comment: huh?what if i remove now()?

Comment: @VincentReguindin It will balance things out, yet if you don't have a column for the time, then yes, do delete it. Entries need to match in numbers, otherwise your query will fail.

Comment: @VincentReguindin [Shankar's answer covers it all](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19691332/1415724)

Comment: i'd remove it.,.,nothing happens

Comment: @VincentReguindin Did you follow Shankar's answer/recommendations below? And double check your column names etc. spelling/letter-case, it makes a difference having `firstname` and `FirstName` if that's the case.

Comment: @VincentReguindin Also make sure you also deleted the last comma in `'$EmailAddress',NOW())` to now read as `'$EmailAddress'` as the last entry. The recommendations SHOULD work. If not, then there's something wrong elsewhere.

Comment: @VincentReguindin Try this `$con = mysql_connect("localhost","mysql_user","mysql_pwd");` <= being your DB info, then 
`$sql = "insert into studentsrecords(LastName,FirstName,MiddleInitial,Age,Gender,Birthday,Address,EmailAddress)
values ('$LastName','$$FirstName','$MiddleInitial','$Age','$Gender','$Birthday','$Address','$EmailAddress')";` then under that `mysql_query($sql,$con);`

Answer (score 3):

Some common mistakes on your code. Fix these up.

- Change **`'$$FirstName'`** to **`'$FirstName'`** in your mysql query.
- You don't have a connection established to your DB. Proposed by [`antyrat`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/186535/antyrat)
- Remove the `NOW()` from your mysql query. Proposed by [`andrewsi`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1315962/andrewsi)

Comment: Was going to mention the very same thing in a comment ;-) Good catch

Comment: You might also want to add that he's adding one more value than there are columns :)

Comment: Hi fredii . Howz u doing today !!!  @andrewsi. Man you have some binocular eyes !! lol

Comment: <?php
mysql_select_db('rotc',mysql_connect('localhost','root',''))or die(mysql_error());
?>

Comment: @andrewsi ah yes, good catch there too Andrew. About the `NOW()` I do believe.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Good thanks Shankar, hope you are well also ;-) Andrew knows his stuff.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran As per Andrew's comment of "adding one more value then there are columns" [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691298/why-can-i-not-insert-data-in-phpmyadmin-mysql#comment29248131_19691298) ;-)

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran It seems like the OP is having a hard time. Plus using `MySQL_` not good. Oh well, we tried.

Answer (score 0):

replace '$$FirstName' to '$FirstName' check your form method is "post" or not,
check your configuration file.
you may create database connection by following method

```
$user = "xxxx"; //Database Username here
    $pass = "xxxx"; //Database Password here
    $db = "xxxx"; //Database Name here
    $localhost = "xxx"; //Database Server


$link = mysql_pconnect($localhost, $user, $pass);
if ( ! $link )
    die( "Couldn't connect to MySQL" );
mysql_select_db( $db)
    or die ( "Couldn't open $db: ".mysql_error() );
```